# How can i get the value of the contenent of a TD in a TR in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I want to get the value of the td I click
I have a table ,in this table I have many tr and td 
I want to get the value of the td I selected

[image]

```
<table id="table" class="table" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Numero demande</th>
        <th>Date prelevement</th>
        <th>Um executante</th>
        <th>Id preleveur</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



@foreach(var dem in @Model) 
      {

        <tr>
        <td><a id="lienFicheDemande"> @dem.DPR</a></td>
        <td>@dem.Dateprelevement  </td>
        <td>@dem.UM  </td>
        <td>@dem.PRELEVEUR.NOMCOMPLET </td>
        <td id="iddem" hidden="hidden">@dem.DPR<</td>
        </tr>
      }

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" >



        $(document).ready(function (e) {

            $('#lienFicheDemande').click(function (e) {

                alert($('#iddem')[0].innerHTML);


                window.open("Appli/Home/FicheDemande?iddem=" + $('#iddem').value, "nom_popup", " menubar=no");

            });
        });

    </script>
```

i want to pass the value of dem_dpr into the link in javascript

Comment: use `alert($('#iddem').text());`

Comment: make each td id unique by taking an counter variable in side foreach, gave a class to tr. on class click catch the td id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('td').click(function () {
   window.open("Appli/Home/FicheDemande?iddem=" + $(this).text(), "nom_popup"," menubar=no");
   });
  });
```

For every TD, bind click function in each of them. 
.text() function will get only the text in TD out from it.
It is best if you could put ID for the table.
So if you have added ID to the table. The solution would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#table_id td').click(function () {
   window.open("Appli/Home/FicheDemande?iddem=" + $(this).text(), "nom_popup"," menubar=no");
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot use IDs this way.  They need to be unique per document.  Use class instead of IDs.  Then, you can use `.closest('.iddem')` to grab the element closest to the link you clicked and use `.html()` or `.text()` to grab it's value.

Example:

```
<table id="table" class="table" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Numero demande</th>
        <th>Date prelevement</th>
        <th>Um executante</th>
        <th>Id preleveur</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



@foreach(var dem in @Model) 
      {

        <tr>
        <td><a class="lienFicheDemande"> @dem.DPR</a></td>
        <td>@dem.Dateprelevement  </td>
        <td>@dem.UM  </td>
        <td>@dem.PRELEVEUR.NOMCOMPLET </td>
        <td class="iddem" hidden="hidden">@dem.DPR<</td>
        </tr>
      }

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" >



        $(document).ready(function (e) {

            $('.lienFicheDemande').click(function (e) {

                alert($(this).closest('.iddem').html());


                window.open("Appli/Home/FicheDemande?iddem=" + $(this).closest('.iddem').html(), "nom_popup", " menubar=no");

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: $(this).closest('.iddem').html(), may bet we have to use text() function here, he wants value not html ??

Comment: Correct, but I guess it depends on what is inside the td element.  Either .html() or .text() should do what he wants.

Comment: Using `<input type="hidden" class="iddem"/>` would be better than a `<td/>`, or even better as it is only a number, set a `data-` attribute on the `<a>` so you don't need to traverse the DOM

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the hidden="hidden" attribute, which of course does nothing but implies he does not want it to be displayed.